How do I batch copy existing file names and use them as new folder names? then move the files in the created folder
i have many *.iso files in a folder , then i want to create a subfolder for each files based on their file names and move the files to each folder
iso files
run as admin
folders created
i have tried it to create folders and working fine
forfiles /M *.iso /C "cmd /c if not exist @fname\ md @fname"

but now im searching how to modify it and add move command

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Destroy666, yes that question is similar to my needs and solved my issues
